# Vertical spacing in `\newcommand`s

Tags: spacing, macros

Consider the piece of code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\hello}{Hello world!\vspace{12pt}Hello again!}

\begin{document}

\hello

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output.

[image: MWE]

Hopefully it is clear from the code that this is not the intended result.  Is there a way to permit `\newcommand`s to add vertical spacing, or if not, is there another way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: `\par\vspace{12pt}` instead of the `\vspace` alone.

Comment: This is unrelated to the `\newcommand`.  You get exactly the same if you just enter `Hello world!\vspace{12pt}Hello again!` directly into the document.